# Get default file name from download with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I am trying to figure out how to get the default file name of a file I download using an HttpUrlConnection.

I use a REST API to download the file so I can't parse the URL for the name and the "Content-Disposition" header doesn't contain the name either but when I put the link in my browser it will download the file with the right name so I'm thinking it must be possible to get the name from the result of the HTTP request somehow.

I have read the following two posts which addressed this problem without solving it for my particular situation: [HttpURLConnection downloaded file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995378/httpurlconnection-downloaded-file-name) and 
[Get download file name from URL or HttpUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435940/get-download-file-name-from-url-or-httpurlconnection)